# How to use Settings.settings for entity framework connection strings?

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I'd like to store the Entity model connection string in the app.config using the same approach used by old Typed DataSet. Both use the same section: `<connectionStrings>`.

Entity saves the connection as:

`<add name="MyDB_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDB.csdl|res:......" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

Typed DataSet saves as:

`<add name="MyTest.Properties.Settings.MyDbString" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;...."  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

The former is only accessibile using a "not-typed" syntax, like:

`string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB_Entities"].ConnectionString;`

The latter is "wrapped" by Settings.settings. So you can write:

`string s = Settings.Default.MyDbString;`

The Entity entry does not contain the namespace so Settings.settings is not able to parse it.  Any idea /suggestion?